# uninitialized constant I18n::JS Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phusion, openproject

I am still having trouble with Ruby on Rails. I run rails s (this is for my openproject app) and I get this (before it was working). I also wanted to make a note I am now using Ruby 2.0 and I still get the same error.

```
require 'rails/all'... 0.850s
Bundler.require... 7.700s
/home/bistro/openproject/config/application.rb:89:in `<class:Application>': uninitialized constant I18n::JS (NameError)
        from /home/bistro/openproject/config/application.rb:61:in `<module:OpenProject>'
        from /home/bistro/openproject/config/application.rb:60:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/bistro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
        from /home/bistro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /home/bistro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
        from /home/bistro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I also wanted to comment, I have i18n installed

Comment: I got a little farther I removed the middleware line in application.rb and now when I run bundle exec to get the server started I get this..

Comment: Bundler.require... 7.130s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.16 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000

Comment: => Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Application.initialize!... Exiting
/home/bistro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load': /home/bistro/openproject/config/initializers/i18n-js.rb:67: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end (SyntaxError)
18n::JS.export

Comment: looks like you want to use the `i18n-js` gem, but it is missing

Comment: I have that gem installed and it is still giving me the error.

Comment: Just to be sure, I installed it again, and it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: Do you still experience this error with a recent checkout of the `dev` branch from github?

Comment: You should consider adding all these info to the question. Was your question resolved by one of the answers? If so, you should accept that answer.

Answer (score 4):

I'm working on a Rails Ember app and I had exactly the same problem, trying to internationalize the client-side using the i18n-js gem (https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js). To give more context, I am following the instructions in this article: http://eviltrout.com/2013/11/24/i18n-in-ember.html

In my case, Rails did not find `I18n::JS` because it is now called `SimplesIdeias::I18n` (you can see it by running `rake middleware` from the command line). Adding the line

```
config.middleware.use SimplesIdeias::I18n::Middleware
```

in the application.rb file solved the problem for me, hope it helps.

Comment: Pretty lame for the gem authors not to tell us about this change. They updated the gem only 3 days ago.

Comment: @Adrien so did this resolve your issue? Because I get NameError: uninitialized constant MyApp::Application::SimplesIdeias after prepending SimplesIdeias::. (Maybe also interesting for the author of this answer.)

Answer (score 0):

If you happen upon this now adays. your gemfile should say something like gem 'i18n-js', ">= 3.0.0.rc11". Otherwise you will end up using version 2.0

Comment: Unfortunately my gemfile reads exactly this.